# Finding (multiset) difference between two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multiset

Given arrays (say row vectors) A and B, how do I find an array C such that merging B and C will give A?

For example, given

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5];
B = [2, 3, 5, 5];
```

then

```
C = multiset_diff(A, B) % Should be [4, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5]
```

(the order of the result does not matter here).

For the same A, if `B = [2, 4, 5]`, then the result should be `[6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5]`.

(Since there were two `4`s in A and one `4` in B, the result C should have 2 - 1 = 1 `4` in it.  Similarly for the other values.)

PS: Note that `setdiff` would remove all instances of 2, 3, and 5, whereas here they need to be removed just however many times they appear in B.

---

**Performance**: I ran some quick-n-dirty benchmarks locally, here are the results for future reference:

- @heigele's nested loop method performs best for small lengths of A (say upto N = 50 or so elements). It does 3x better for small (N=20) `A`s, and 1.5x better for medium-sized (N=50) `A`s, compared to the next best method - which is:
- @obchardon's `histc`-based method. This is the one performs the best when A's size N starts to be 100 and above. For eg., this does 3x better than the above nested loop method when N = 200.

@matt's for+find method does comparably to the histc method for small N, but quickly degrades in performance for larger N (which makes sense since the entire `C == B(x)` comparison is run every iteration).

(The other methods are either several times slower or invalid at the time of writing.)

Comment: What do you mean by merge?  How does one merge [2,3,5,5] with [4,6,4,3,1,5] and get [2,4,6,4,3,3,1,5,5,5]?  Do you just want the same numerical values in any random order?  Such that `D = cat(2,B,C)`?

Comment: @Matt "same numerical values in any random order" Pretty much, yes. The "merge" here is conceptual rather than a specific algorithmic process, meant to illustrate what the expected result would be like. Going with `D = cat(2, B, C)`, then D should be a permutation of A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still another approach using the `histc` function:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5];
B = [2, 3, 5, 5];

uA  = unique(A);
hca = histc(A,uA); 
hcb = histc(B,uA);
res = repelem(uA,hca-hcb)
```

We simply calculate the number of repeated elements for each vectors according to the unique value of vector A, then we use repelem to create the result.

This solution do not preserve the initial order but it don't seems to be a problem for you.

I use `histc` for Octave compatibility, but this function is deprecated so you can also use `histcounts`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a vectorized way. Memory-inefficient, mostly for fun:

```
tA = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, A, A.')), 1);
tB = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, B, B.')), 1);
result = setdiff([A; tA].', [B; tB].', 'rows', 'stable');
result = result(:,1).';
```

The idea is to make each entry unique by tagging it with an occurrence number. The vectors become 2-column matrices, `setdiff` is applied with the `'rows'` option, and then the tags are removed from the result.

Comment: Clever approach.  I started down that path but didn't see the path out of the `bsxfun` woods.  Well done sir.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the second output of `ismember` to find the indexes where elements of `B` are in `A`, and `diff` to remove duplicates:

This answer assumes that `B` is already sorted. If that is not the case, `B` has to be sorted before executing above solution.

For the first example:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5];
B = [2, 3, 5, 5];
%B = sort(B); Sort if B is not sorted.
[~,col] = ismember(B,A);
indx = find(diff(col)==0);
col(indx+1) = col(indx)+1;
A(col) = [];
C = A;

>>C

4     6     4     3     1     5
```

For the second example:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5];
B = [2, 4, 5, 5];
%B = sort(B); Sort if B is not sorted.
[~,col] = ismember(B,A);
indx = find(diff(col)==0);
col(indx+1) = col(indx)+1;
A(col) = [];
C = A;
>>C

6     4     3     3     1     5
```

Comment: @sundar I have updated my answer, solution works properly for both examples.

Comment: @sundar Yes that was the assumption. Thanks, I have edited the answer with your correct remark.

Comment: Oh, this also seems to assume B will only have at most 2 repetitions of an element - for eg., `B = [2, 4, 5, 5, 5]` doesn't return `[6, 4, 3, 3, 1]`, instead leaves in a `5` too.

Comment: You should consider making your question clearer next time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a fan of loops, but for random perturbations of `A` this was the best I came up with.

```
C = A;
for x = 1:numel(B)
C(find(C == B(x), 1, 'first')) = [];
end
```

I was curious about looking at the affect of different orders of `A` on a solution approach so I setup a test like this:

```
Ctruth = [1 3 3 4 5 5 6];
for testNumber = 1:100
    Atest = A(randperm(numel(A)));
    C = myFunction(Atest,B);
    C = sort(C);
    assert(all(C==Ctruth));
end
```

Comment: I'm about to accept this, as this is a straightforward approach that is also be the fastest among the answers here (per some quick local benchmarks I tried). But could you rearrange the answer so that the code for finding the difference comes first, to be clearer to future readers?

Comment: @sundar that makes sense, I've pasted the code on the top.  How that helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post. Unfortunately it looks like this method doesn't scale well when A starts to get large, quickly growing several times slower (as the update in the question mentions). So I'll likely end up accept @obchardon's answer instead since that scales better. Sorry!

Comment: @sundar Which is exactly why I don't normally use `for` loops, but for simple examples (like the one you provided) it's normally not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Strongly inspired by Matt, but on my machine 40% faster:

```
function A = multiDiff(A,B)
for j = 1:numel(B)
    for i = 1:numel(A)
        if A(i) == B(j)
            A(i) = [];
            break;
        end
    end
end
end
```