# Finding removed elements in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, repeat, pruning

I have a process that is iteratively and randomly pruning a huge vector of integers and I want to find what elements are removed between each iteration. This vector has a lot of repetitions and using ismember() and setdiff() doesn't helped me much.

As an illustration if X = [1,10,8,5,10,3,5,2]:

```
step 0: X = 1,10,8,5,10,3,5,2
step 1: X = 1,10,8,10,3,5,2 (5 is removed)
step 2: X = 1,10,8,3,2 (10 and 5 are removed)
step 3: X = 10,8,3,2 (1 is removed)
step 4: X = 2 (10, 8 and 3 are removed)
step 5: X = [] (2 is finally removed)
```

I aim at finding the elements removed at each steps (ie. 5 then, 10 and 5 and so on). I could possibly find an overly complicated solution using `hist(X, unique(X))` between steps, but I assume there exists a much more elegant (and cheaper!) solution in matlab.

Comment: How large is `X` and how many unique elements does it have, typically?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to have this process (a function I presume) also return the removed element?

Comment: Also, are the values always positive integers?

Comment: @LuisMendo X typically contains hundreds and at most a thousands and yes values are always positive.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sure it would, the issue is that the process generating X  values takes a huge time to compute and I am processing the results tight now.

Comment: @Grasshoper I don't understand your last comment about the process generating the X values. Can you clarify?

Comment: And if `X` only contains a few thousand elements, wouldn't `find` be quick enough?

Comment: @beaker The process that generates the X values is the pruning of the elements of a huge structure according to some strategy and constraints. Not sure how to use find() in the given context, do you suggest to use a loop and counts the frequency of each element? That is building a histogram.

Comment: @Grasshoper No, I wasn't suggesting a histogram approach. Given two arrays `X` and `Y`, find the first element where `X ~= Y`. This is the first removed element. Now apply to the remaining arrays *after* the mismatch. The solution is *O(kn)*, where `k` is the number of removed elements and `n` is the length of `X`. However that's probably slower and more coding than the `histc(unique)` solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829635/finding-multiset-difference-between-two-arrays).

Comment: @beaker yes, got it.

Comment: @Grasshoper Marking as duplicate then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This approach is **memory-intensive**. It computes an intermediate matrix of size `N`x`M` where `N` is the number of elements of `X` and `M` is the number of unique elements of `X`, using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). This may be feasible or not depending on your typical `N` and `M`.

   ```
   X = [1,10,8,5,10,3,5,2];
   Y = [8,10,2,1]; % removed 10, 5, 5, 3. Order in Y is arbitrary
   u = unique(X(:).');
   removed = repelem(u, sum(X(:)==u,1)-sum(Y(:)==u,1));
   ```

   gives

   ```
   removed =
        3     5     5    10
   ```

   For Matlab versions before R2016b, you need [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of implicit expansion:

   ```
   removed = repelem(u, sum(bsxfun(@eq,X(:),u),1)-sum(bsxfun(@eq,Y(:),u),1));
   ```
2. If the values in `X` are always **positive integers**, a **more efficient** approach can be used, employing [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to compute the number of times each element appears:

   ```
   X = [1,10,8,5,10,3,5,2];
   Y = [8,10,2,1]; % removed 10, 5, 5, 3. Order in Y is arbitrary
   removed = repelem(1:max(X), sparse(1,X,1) - sparse(1,Y,1));
   ```

Comment: This works fine and is neat! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the idea to recover the input from the output by subtracting both and iterating the differing values, which then are the to be found indices of the removed elements.

```
% Input.
X = [1, 10, 8, 5, 10, 3, 5, 2];

% Remove indices for the given example.
y = { [4], [4 6], [1], [1 2 3], [1] };

% Simulate removing.
for k = 1:numel(y)

  % Remove elements.
  temp = X;
  temp(y{k}) = [];

  % Determine number of removed elements.
  nRemoved = numel(X) - numel(temp);

  % Find removed elements by recovering input from output.
  recover = temp;
  removed = zeros(1, nRemoved);
  for l = 1:nRemoved
    tempdiff = X - [recover zeros(1, nRemoved - l + 1)];
    idx = find(tempdiff, 1);
    removed(l) = X(idx);
    recover = [recover(1:idx-1) X(idx) recover(idx:end)];
  end

  % Simple, stupid output.
  disp('Input:');
  disp(X);
  disp('');
  disp('Output:');
  disp(temp);
  disp('');
  disp('Removed elements:');
  disp(removed);
  disp('');
  disp('------------------------------');

  % Reset input.
  X = temp;

end
```

Output for the given example:

```
Input:
    1   10    8    5   10    3    5    2

Output:
    1   10    8   10    3    5    2

Removed elements:
 5

------------------------------
Input:
    1   10    8   10    3    5    2

Output:
    1   10    8    3    2

Removed elements:
   10    5

------------------------------
Input:
    1   10    8    3    2

Output:
   10    8    3    2

Removed elements:
 1

------------------------------
Input:
   10    8    3    2

Output:
 2

Removed elements:
   10    8    3

------------------------------
Input:
 2

Output:
[](1x0)

Removed elements:
 2

------------------------------
```

Is that an appropriate solution, or am I missing some (obvious) inefficiencies?

Comment: Thank you. The solution seem correct but the solution provided by @Luis-mendo would seem more efficient.